# How to display company name "only" on friends work history (facebook api)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been getting my facebook friends work history. But the result is an array whose content is as follows :

```
 {
 "id": "xxx", 
 "friends": {
"data": [
  {
    "name": "Indiarto Priadi", 
    "work": [
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "111178415566505", 
          "name": "Liputan 6 SCTV"
        }
      }, 
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "107900732566334", 
          "name": "SCTV"
        }
      }
    ], 
    "id": "502163984"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Agustin Kertawijaya", 
    "work": [
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "138215336225242", 
          "name": "Trader Corporation (Canada)"
        }, 
        "location": {
          "id": "110941395597405", 
          "name": "Toronto, Ontario"
        }, 
        "position": {
          "id": "168673399850791", 
          "name": "Desktop operator <Pre press>"
        }, 
        "start_date": "2006-06-01", 
        "end_date": "2008-06-01"
      }, 
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "114464911939560", 
          "name": "Merrill Corporation Canada"
        }, 
        "location": {
          "id": "110941395597405", 
          "name": "Toronto, Ontario"
        }, 
        "position": {
          "id": "190075304347365", 
          "name": "Financial Print Project Manager"
        }, 
        "start_date": "2006-06-01", 
        "end_date": "2011-10-01"
      }
    ], 
    "id": "511990261"
  }
], 
"paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1065251285/friends?limit=2&fields=name,work&offset=2&__after_id=511990261"
}
```

}
}

Now i want to display "only" the employer name on my page, but i can't find the way to do that. 
Here is my code :

```
$userFriends = $facebook->api('/'.$userId.'/friends');

for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){ //retrieved friends (max 4 persons)
        $value=$userFriends["data"][$i];
        echo "<div id='$value[id]'>";
        $profile = $facebook->api("/".$value["id"]);
        $friendsWork = $facebook->api("/".$value["id"]."?fields=work");
        echo "<strong>".$profile["name"]."<br></strong>";
        echo " <img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$value["id"]."/picture'><br>";
        echo "Username : ".$profile["username"]."<br>";
        echo "Local : ".$profile["locale"]."<br>";
        echo "Birthdate : ".$profile["birthday"]."<br>";

        print_r($friendsWork); // <--- the result is an array

        echo "<hr>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Does anyone know how to display the company(employer) name only?
any answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: decode from json to object or array, then fetch whatever info you want.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: would you give me the code? I have tried the json-decode but only return error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, nothing fancy, I just did what I said in my comment

```
$json = '{
 "id": "xxx",
 "friends": {
"data": [
  {
    "name": "Indiarto Priadi",
    "work": [
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "111178415566505",
          "name": "Liputan 6 SCTV"
        }
      },
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "107900732566334",
          "name": "SCTV"
        }
      }
    ],
    "id": "502163984"
  },
  {
    "name": "Agustin Kertawijaya",
    "work": [
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "138215336225242",
          "name": "Trader Corporation (Canada)"
        },
        "location": {
          "id": "110941395597405",
          "name": "Toronto, Ontario"
        },
        "position": {
          "id": "168673399850791",
          "name": "Desktop operator <Pre press>"
        },
        "start_date": "2006-06-01",
        "end_date": "2008-06-01"
      },
      {
        "employer": {
          "id": "114464911939560",
          "name": "Merrill Corporation Canada"
        },
        "location": {
          "id": "110941395597405",
          "name": "Toronto, Ontario"
        },
        "position": {
          "id": "190075304347365",
          "name": "Financial Print Project Manager"
        },
        "start_date": "2006-06-01",
        "end_date": "2011-10-01"
      }
    ],
    "id": "511990261"
  }
],
"paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1065251285/friends?limit=2&fields=name,work&offset=2&__after_id=511990261"
}}}'; // remember the last two closing curlys, you left them out of the code block in the OP.

  $obj = json_decode($json);

  foreach ($obj->friends->data as $friend) {
    echo '<h1>' . $friend->name . '</h1>';
    foreach ($friend->work as $job) {
      echo 'Employee: ' . $job->employer->name . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
  }
```

Output:

```
Indiarto Priadi

Employee: Liputan 6 SCTV
Employee: SCTV
--------------------------------------

Agustin Kertawijaya

Employee: Trader Corporation (Canada)
Employee: Merrill Corporation Canada
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to parse the array you obtained, like this-

```
$userFriends = $facebook->api('/'.$userId.'/friends?fields=work,name');

foreach($userFriends['data'] as $friend)
{
   $friend_name = $friend['name'];
   $emp_name=array();
   // list of all employers of this friend
   if(isset($friend['work']))
   {
       foreach($friend['work'] as $work)
       {
         array_push($emp_name, $work['employer']['name']);
       }
   } 
   else
   {
       $emp_name = "N.A.";
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to echo the $emp_name and showing error : 'Notice: Undefined index: work in PATH\index.php on line 95 (on the 2nd foreach)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PATH\index.php on line 95'

Comment: actually, all of the users might not have the work info available on facebook. I've edited the answer, please check.

Comment: still showing same error. I still dont understand why it errors at the 2nd foreach

Comment: Have you used the exact code? Can you show me the exact error? I've edited the code further pls check